# Transformation Matrix Jordan Form--How Do I Start?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

For this question, I am asked to find the Jordan form of a certain transformation matrix ("M", which = PJP^-1, where J = Jordan normal form) by which p(x) --> p'(x) - 2p(x), and where P2-->P2. I'm not sure how to translate this into numbers, except that the basis for P2 is either 1+x+x^2 or (1 0 0 , 0 1 0, 0 0 1). Any tips would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: well, a basis for $P^2$ is $1,x,x^2$. Where are those elements sent by the transformation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's what I don't understand about the question myself! I'm not sure onto which numbers that basis is being transformed. The only information the question gives is that p(x) becomes p'(x) - 2p(x). The way the question is set up is leaving me confused, since there aren't any actual numbers.